# Zend Framework 3 tutorial Routing and Controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to do the tutorial for Zend Framework 3. I get to the end of this page (https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/) and when I go to localhost:8090 i get the following error:

```
[ Model\AlbumTable::class => function($container) { $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\AlbumTableGateway::class); return new Model\AlbumTable($tableGateway); }, Model\AlbumTableGateway::class => function ($container) { $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class); $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet(); $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Album()); return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype); }, ], ]; } public function getControllerConfig() { return [ 'factories' => [ Controller\AlbumController::class => function($container) { return new Controller\AlbumController( $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class) ); }, ], ]; } }
```

If I comment out 'Album' in module.config.php it will load the basic framework. My composer.json file has "Album\": "module/Album/src/" and I ran $ composer dump-autoload.

I've checked everything and can't figure out what is wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

```
    namespace Album;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [

    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'album' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];

<? php 

namespace Album;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

     public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Model\AlbumTable::class => function($container) {
                    $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\AlbumTableGateway::class);
                    return new Model\AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                },
                Model\AlbumTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                    $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
     public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\AlbumController::class => function($container) {
                    return new Controller\AlbumController(
                        $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class)
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

I also get this error message:
127.0.0.1:52590 [500]: / - Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Album) could not be initialized. in /cygdrive/c/users/kafka/dropbox/zf-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:203
Stack trace:

## 0 /cygdrive/c/users/kafka/dropbox/zf-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(175): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

## 1 /cygdrive/c/users/kafka/dropbox/zf-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(97): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Album')

## 2 /cygdrive/c/users/kafka/dropbox/zf-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

## 3 /cygdrive/c/users/kafka/dropbox/zf-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

## 4 /cygdrive/c/users/kaf in /cygdrive/c/users/kafka/dropbox/zf-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203

Comment: What you have posted is not an error, it's the contents of you service config function. In what situation are you seeing this?

Comment: I'm attempting the Zend Framework 3 tutorial. I've done the pages: Modules, Routing and Controllers, and Database and Models. At this point, I should be able to see the Album module when I enter the url. However, I get the message posted above in the browser. I also see the error I've posted above.

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem here, just syntax. So thanks Tim Fountain, but no more assistance is required.